# Unwanted content in Cornered UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, cornerradius

I am trying to Crop the *UIImageView* using its *Layer.CornerRadius* property to get a round Image (Like whatsapp dp) but the results are surprising. The image shows unwanted content from the previous page. [Please take a look at the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPIf.png)

Comment: Put some code, so know what are you doing, also screenshot of your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't add mask to your image. Do you set `clipToBounds = true` ?

Comment: Yes it did. Silly me!

Comment: @rohHitnaik ok, that's small thing which brake your project :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have added A background image in that image !!! make sure there is no background image and set  clear color of  background color of that image!!!

Comment: Could you please make your answer NOT look like a source code? Thanks!